# How to re-enable region?

Tags: emacs

This is my use case:

- I enable a region.
- Then run a command that disables the highlighting of the region.

Now I want to run a command that requires the region to be enabled, but it is no longer. How do I enable it again? I know the region is active (c-x c-x shows me the other end of the region).

I have tried c-u c-x c-x but it does not work for me.

Any ideas what command I should run?

Comment: What command do you mean that requires the region to be enabled and doesn't work when it is not highlighted?

Comment: Multiple cursors edit line: mc/edit-lines. I use a "chord" of two keys to use it, but sometimes the timing between the pressing of the two keys is not fast enough, and the region is disabled. This command only works on the "active" region.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `C-x C-x` to (re-)activate the region.  That swaps point and the mark, so if you want to put them back where they were then just repeat it: `C-x C-x C-x C-x` (hold down Control and hit `x` 4 times).